# How to (properly) tag Python regex questions

Tags: discussion, tags

I am mostly active on the various [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tags. I am also a *"fan"* of [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) (regex) and tend to enter questions to see if I can help or learn something new. I also like to curate the site where I can by editing and I sometimes get confused about how to tag those questions.

There is, of course, the widely used [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) tag. But Python has its built-in library for dealing with regex, with its own tag - [re](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/re).

Now, [re](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/re) is only tagged in [544 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/re?sort=newest), while there are around [35k questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+regex) tagged with [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) and [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex).

The thing is, that questions about regex with Python are mostly using `re` (I doubt anyone implement their own Python regex engine...). How should I tag Python regex questions? Should I tag them with both `re` and `regex`, or just `re` to avoid cluttering the tags?
Or alternatively just `regex`? The reject tag edit message (from the Suggested Edit review queue) states:

> This edit introduces tags that do not help to define the topic of the
> question. Tags should help to describe what the question is **about**, not
> just **what it contains**.

<sup>*emphasis mine</sup>

According to this, one might say that `re` is part of what the question ***contains*** and `regex` already defines what the question is ***about***. In that case, why do we even need the `re` tag?

Comment: IMO, it depends, if the post is about the regex itself, use [tag:regex], if the post is about how to use `re`, use [tag:re]

Comment: There's also a tag for a 3rd party module [python-regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-regex) called [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) on pypi

Comment: *"I doubt anyone implement their own Python regex engine"* - why not? New libraries appears every day, e.g. [tag:json.net] shouldn't be used for every [tag:json] question. Don't tag everything with [tag:re]! Also, there could be language-agnosic questions, so don't tag everything with [tag:python] either.

Comment: They should be tagged with Python and Regex, of course. If it's about using Re to do it, also tag it with Re.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sentence #1 from https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info:

> Regular expressions provide a declarative language to match patterns within strings.

`regex` refers to the pattern used to find matches within a string. This is true regardless of language and is the most commonly requested aspect for assistance.

Using `re` to execute the `regex` is a different ballgame. Ditto for using `python-regex` for executing a `regex` pattern. I will focus on `re` for this answer.

If someone posts "How to enable the dotall flag?" or "How to loop all matches?" then `python` and `re` are technically all that's needed since we probably don't have to alter the regex expression itself (assuming it's correct, which it rarely is).

However if the question is "Pattern not working as expected" then `python` and `regex` are acceptable tags. If it turns out that the answer is "You need to turn on the dotall flag" then it is safe to add the `re` tag.

In contrast to PHP where you need to literally add `/s` to the regex string so one would not add a tag for `preg_replace` nor `preg_match`.

Comment: *"How to loop all matches?"* - why [tag:re] tag for this? Typo?

Comment: @Sinatr No typo. To loop matches you need `re.finditer()` which is part of the `re` library. The `for` loop is a language construct in Python so no additional tags would be needed.

Comment: Matches is [tag:regex] term (so this tag make sense to add) and matches are returned for an input. If question is "How do I get results of my _insert_re_stuff_here", then it's `re`. "How to loop all matches" is likely language-agnostic regex-pattern question, though [tag:re] would be neccessary if OP attempt is done using `re`.

Comment: @Sinatr How else would you suggest to do it in Python?

Comment: `[python][regex]` - in general, if you accept answer using another python library too. `[python][re]` - implementation specific questions, you know the problem is not expression; to report bugs or query about library feature. `[python][regex][re]` - re-specific regex question (not allowed to use anything else). `[regex]` - language agnostic question. `[regex][re]` or just `[re]` - don't use, language tag is important, disregards re is python currently, it could change.

Comment: Thank you, that already clears up some confusion: pattern problems - `regex` ; functional problems - `re`/`python-regex`

Comment: @Sinatr Sure that sounds fine; good luck enforcing it. Most people asking regex questions have no clue if their problem is Python string interpolation, a library/function issue, iteration problem, or pattern issue so tagging with `python` and `regex` is the best way to ensure enough eyeballs land on the question; the other tags are after-thoughts.

Comment: @Tomerikoo Glad I could help. Don't blindly update tags; you'd have to read each question individually and assess whether `re` is applicable.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Of course! That is always true and I follow it no worries. It's just that as a silly human-being it is always easier to have some rule-of-thumb to follow :)

Comment: I mean, there are cases where `python` + `regex` could be mapped to `re` in a formulaic  way - basically anything with "variable width lookbehind/lookahead" is going to be an `re` issue - but then the answer will probably be `python-regex` anyway so . . .

Comment: @DanielF Why would a variable width lookahead require `python-regex`?

Answer (score 5):

There are also other kinds of regex "engines" available to Pythonistas, for example, https://pypi.org/project/regex/ which adds functionality above and beyond Python's `re` implementation. Those could be tagged [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) + [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) but not [re](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/re) as differences are implementation dependent.

Unless you know for sure if the code uses `re` or `regex` - better not retag them.

If you need a pypi.regex and re - compatible regex you could even use both :D

---

I just saw [the comment by Jon Clements](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402922/how-to-properly-tag-python-regex-questions?cb=1#comment808549_402922) - about there being a [python-regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-regex) tag specifically for https://pypi.org/project/regex/.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. My question came up after recently encountering a question about regex in python simply tagged `python`. That got me confused on how would be best to add the regex part to the tags. I would usually not mess too much with tags that seem to already be relevant (regarding your remark about *better not retag them*)